# Angular Bug IE10 variable in style attribute

Tags: angularjs

If I do something like this:

```
<div style="margin-left: 50px;">TEST1</div>
<div style="margin-left: {{50}}px;">TEST2</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XeVHL/1/

The margin-left of the value test2 will not be applied, and this only in IE, any suggestion for a work around this?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a workaround you could use `ng-style`:

```
<div ng-style="{ 'margin-left': 50 + 'px'}">TEST2 {{50}}</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YXe8Z/

Answer (score 1):

About the bug, it's strange that only IE behaves this way.
Anyway, you could [`ng-style`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle) directive for this purpose - because if you're going to wait until Angular parse that interpolation and correctly apply the style, it's better to do it with proper directives :)

```
<div ng-style="{ 'margin-left': 50 + 'px' }">TEST2</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q4UKD/

Comment: Thank you Gustavo but Jason was a bit faster than you on this ;)

Answer (score 0):

**ng-style vs style** 
Just a quick tip – use **‘ ‘** for defining a property in ng-style. Eg use ‘margin-left’ in place of margin-left, as it works fine if only one word property like width. width, top, left… doesn’t required to be ‘width’, ‘top’, ‘left’ but for good practice use ‘width’.