# ng-style won't work for dynamic div height

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to use a $watch expression to resize a set of  depending on the current height and width of the browser window:

```
$scope.watchWindowDimensions = function () {
    return wholeWindow.height();
};

$scope.$watch($scope.watchWindowDimensions(), function () {
    $scope.windowDimensions = {
      divHeight: function () {
        return (wholeWindow.height() - otherElement.outerHeight());
      }
    };
}, true);

wholeWindow.bind('resize', function () {
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

With the HTML code looking like this:

```
<div class="container" ng-style="{
    'height': windowDimensions.divHeight() + 'px !important', 
    'overflow-y': 'scroll !important;'
}">
```

Note that divHeight being a function is just my latest experiment. I have also tried using a traditional variable as well as a concatenated string.

Now, the problem: The div gets no inline style at all from any of these solutions as seen here in the Chrome debugger:

[image: here].

I've managed to get this working fine using the plain style="{{...}}" tag. However, due to the bug described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014765/angular-bug-ie10-variable-in-style-attribute) this will not work in IE10+, which I have to support.

Can someone give me some pointers on how to get this to work?

Comment: Does it work with just the `overflow` property? If not, something else is wrong.

Comment: isherwood: Removing everything except the overflow property still results in an empty style block as above. Any theories?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm building something similar now and using similar code. `ng-style` should work for you.